# how to get clean version of the html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I wrote an application that uses angularjs for data-binding.
The application is some sort of visual html builder.
When the user is done, I want to allow him to export the HTML.
Since I did massive usage in angularjs, its attributes are all over the place, and the generated HTML is ugly.

Is there anyway to get clean version of the HTML?
this example will export the ugly html: http://jsfiddle.net/ga25hep2/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div id="the_html" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
<button onclick='exportMe()'>export</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}

function exportMe(){
    alert(document.getElementById('the_html').outerHTML)
}
```

Comment: eventually, you want to strip everything that starts with ng- from your html.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller - yes, I think so. Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: some regexpression to replace them with an empty string.

Comment: actually you could use the following regexpressions: `(ng-\w+)|(\w*="\s*")` to replace with an empty char.

Comment: Unless you have a very complicated regex, it won't remove the class attribute entirely. E.g. in the case of `class="ng-binding"`, so you'll be left with `class=""`. Extra stuff you don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can update angular to a version after 1.3 (you really should, there are lots of other benefits, too), then you can disable all of the `ng-` class spam by disabling debug info in your app:

```
myApp.config(function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
});
```

You can see the result in an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ga25hep2/1/).

Note that I changed the structure of things slightly but the functionality is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it exists a native way to do this. AngularJS is not about such kind of work.

Just write a script that parses your exported code and remove each ng-* attribute

Answer (score 0):

We need to iterate through all the dom nodes and remove the ng related attributes and ng related classes.

```
function exportMe(){
    var targetEl = document.getElementById('the_html');
    var nodes = targetEl.querySelectorAll('*');

    nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes); // convert NodeList to array
    nodes.unshift(targetEl); // include the root node while iterating.

    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        Array.prototype.slice.call(node.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
            var classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.classList); // conver classList to array
            classes = classes.filter(function (cls) {
                return !(cls.indexOf('ng-') === 0 || cls.indexOf('data-ng-') === 0);
            });

            // remove ng related classes
            node.setAttribute('class', classes.join(' '));

            // remove ng related attributes
            if(attr.name.indexOf('ng-') === 0 || attr.name.indexOf('data-ng-') === 0) { 
                node.removeAttribute(attr.name);
            }
        })
    });    
    alert(targetEl.outerHTML)
}
```

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ga25hep2/2/